# How do chatbots like Trim and Plum link your facebook messenger account to their own third-party accounts and also bank accounts?

Tags: facebook, authorization, chatbot, facebook-access-token, facebook-chatbot

My question is how do bots like Trim and Plum keep track of banking information and also your Facebook messenger link to their own accounts. I understand the account linking workflow Facebook provides, but to support this kind of login system you MUST store a link between Facebook / messenger IDs (PSIDs or ASIDs) and account credentials (or a persistent authentication token) on your systems (i.e. in a database). Yet Trim claims they store "no banking credentials." Is that just an exaggeration for encrypted data or an authentication token?

Also, is there a way to use "Facebook login" for Facebook messenger? I see a lot of 'Get Started' buttons at the bottom of Facebook chats.

Comment: They use a protocol called OAuth & OpenID Connect

Answer (score 0):

In account linking, because the PSID is returned after the user completes your auth flow, the PSID essentially becomes the trusted identity of the user, rather than any account credential.

You could use FB login through Messenger in the webview, but it would be kinda clunky.